# How do I quit Banshee?

Tags: sound, banshee, indicator-sound

When I press the X button in Banshee's title bar, it hides, but the music continues playing. However, from time to time I need to quit Banshee completely. How can I do that? (pressing "close" from the menu bar doesn't help)

I know I could go for running `killall banshee` but that's not an elegant solution. Any other ideas? Is it even possible?

EDIT: After first few answers I noticed I must underline, I do **not** want to stop the music playback, I do **not** want to hide Banshee's window. What I want is to quit **Banshee** totally, in order f.e. to start JACK audio server (and for example restart Banshee).

Comment: I reworded my answer a bit to make it more clear.  Because of the Sound Menu specification, you need to pause Banshee, then press 'close' -- which is why everyone is telling you to press pause. :)

Comment: What a curious design decision. Perhaps progressive and innovative, but to leave out the option of properly _quitting_ the program from the menubar is.. perplexing. I elected to deinstall banshee entirely and use a different program.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This behavior -- which came about as a result of [this bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=634895) -- is a design decision based on the [Ubuntu Sound Menu specification](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoundMenu#Music_player_section).  To quote from the spec:

> A compliant player should also keep playing if you close its window while it is playing; exit if you close its window while it is not playing...

If you have Banshee's sound menu integration turned on, pressing the 'x' won't quit the program while music is playing.  **To quit Banshee, you must first pause the music.**

Comment: I do know that! It's cool it hides instead of closing, but in some cases I need to quit the application totally.

Comment: Re-read the last line of my answer (I'll make it bold so it's more clear).  You can't quit Banshee while music is playing, so first you need to pause the music, then press the 'x'.

Comment: That's it! I missed the fact the playback must be paused first. Great thanks, that solved my problem entirely :)

Comment: No worries.  It's my fault for giving you a long-winded answer full of background information, and hiding the actual solution in the last sentence. :)  Anyway, glad I could help.

Comment: I think that there should still be an option to quit. Ctrl-W and the close-button (x) close the window, but IMHO, the quit menu item and Ctrl-Q shortcut should remain...

Comment: @Simon, I agree completely.  I think it's confusing to have the same button/menu-item behave differently in different situations (music playing vs music paused).

Answer (score 7):

You can't normally close banshee because Ubuntu Team has added a plug-in that integrates Banshee with the Unity desktop. You have to disable that plug-in in the "Preferences" menu to have an "Exit" option (Or CTRL+Q).

1.- Go to Edit > Preferences

2.- Go to the "Plug-ins" tab and disable the "Sound Menu Integration" plug-in.

3.- To REALLY quit Banshee, press CTRL+Q or Go to Multimedia >Exit

Hope it helps.

P.S. I don't like this kind of changes in Ubuntu, think that they should let the applications like they're released. With these constant and radical changes, Canonical is losing points against another distributions.

Answer (score 6):

**Note** - you need to **pause** whatever is playing first otherwise all of the following methods will only close the window but Banshee will remain running in the sound indicator.

---

Click `Media -> Close` (`Media -> Quit` for Ubuntu < 11.04):

[image: banshee close]

or

press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>

or

press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> for Ubuntu < 11.04)

or

right click on the launcher item and click 'Quit':

[image: banshee quit launcher]

Comment: Thanks to you too for the shortcuts (usefull!) and screenshot :D The point I missed was to pause the music first.

Answer (score 0):

See the little sound icon on your top right in the panel? Click on it and hit pause ;)

Comment: I do not want to pause music playback. I need to restart Banshee, because I have switched the sound server and the audio is stuck. Or I may need to quit the whole application to start the JACK audio server. Pausing the playback is not enough, I need to quit the application.

Comment: Then you might as well assign a shortcut to `killall` ;)

Comment: I might. But that's not the reccomended way to close applications, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

You can Quit Banshee by : Menubar > Media > Quit ;)

Comment: or you hit Ctrl-Q with Banshee focused/active :-)

Comment: It doesn't help. It also just hides Banshee, but the program is still running. @Cristoph: this shortcut does not seem to work at all - no reaction.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that Media > Quit (and the Ctrl-Q shortcut) do not exist in Ubuntu Natty with the Sound Menu extension active (as it is by default in Natty).  This is a result of this commit: http://git.gnome.org/browse/banshee/commit/?id=bd1e65