# Banshee still works after I closed it

Tags: banshee

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I quit Banshee?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37656/how-do-i-quit-banshee)

the problem with Banshee in Ubuntu. After I closed It, Banshee still works. I hear sound but I cannot find it using Alt+Tab.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't say if what you want is to entirely close Banshee, or bring it back after you closed it.

If you want it back, try clicking on the sound icon on the panel (top left, where the volume controls are). There's a menu item that says "Banshee". That will bring Banshee up.

The answer to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/37656/how-do-i-quit-banshee) explains why Banshee works this way (i.e. it continues playing music even after you've "closed" it.

If what you want is to entirely quit Banshee, the question I linked to before has the answer (To quit Banshee, you must first pause the music.).